# How come Torah does not have a distinctive word for "wife"?

Tags: hebrew, marriage, language

[Edited] In Bereshit, Torah says the woman will be called Isha, that comes from Ish and is parallel to Ish. Later, Torah says Adam gave to אשתו a new name Chava. Now אשתו appears (out of nowhere) as "his wife", not as her name. 
Ish is used as man and Baal is used as husband, but Isha did not change and means both.
Interestingly, both Targumim bring a different interpretation on the pasuk "כי מאיש לקחה זאת" - Onkelos proposing "מבעלה" and Yonatan "מגברא". Both oppose Rashi's view that "לשון נופלת על לשון".

Comment: Not really on-topic for this site...

Comment: @ezra, why not? It is asking about word usage in the Torah.

Comment: @AlBerko https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide

Comment: Maybe that's just the way the language works, and dibra Torah kil'shon b'nei adam. In French femme means both wife and woman, while in Spanish mujer means both wife and woman, while in Farsi  زن also means either. The Old English wif, the source for wife, also meant woman. || This appears to be a general linguistic phenomenon, with language probably reflecting usage and regnant culture. [cont.]

Comment: [cont.] || It probably has to do with the notion of women being objects and men, subjects. Thus the man has the woman. She is his woman. 'baal' just means the one who has. Thus, one has a chair, a goat, or a woman. While the chair has an owner; not a man. The object isn't renamed; it keeps its title. It is the owner who is retitled.

Comment: Similarly, in Arabic النساء and زوجة both mean wither wife or woman. And in Greek γυναίκα is the word for wife or woman, same in Lithuanian where žmona means both. Same with Russian and just about every other language...

Comment: @mevaqesh - There's also _die Frau_ in German, and _le femme_ in French, which are used for both woman and wife interchangeably.

Comment: @ezra I already noted femme in my first comment...but thanks for noting frau.

Comment: I edited details, and included Targumim.

Comment: I tried a translation site, saying some 60 out of 100 languages it lists, have a different ford for both, where about 40 use the same. https://www.indifferentlanguages.com/words/wife

Comment: @mevaqesh If the Torah's reason for this convention is " dibra Torah kil'shon b'nei adam," then that assertion, supported, could be a valid answer to this question.

Comment: If I am right, commentaries probably wouldn't discuss it, as it would've seemed normal and unremarkable to them. Thus, while it weakens the question, it cannot really make a sourced answer. @Isaac

Comment: @mevaqesh If you're right, then there should be support available from sources that discuss the general concept and implications of "dibra Torah kil'shon b'nei adam." Being answerable based on general principles doesn't make the question weak. And there's certainly no reason to expect that every question about word choice in Tanach would be answerable based exclusively on commentaries *ad locum*. If you've got knowledge about the Torah that addresses the question, the best place to share it is in the answer box.

Comment: @IsaacMoses You misunderstood me. The fact that this is not unique to Hebrew and is a feature of many if not most (older) languages, makes it a weaker question. Not editing the question to reflect this similarly does not improve the question. I never suggested an answer was poor because it can be answered based on general principles...

Comment: @IsaacMoses You don't have to come on to Dibrah Torah Kelashon Bnei Adam. That is something which is evoked regarding syntax (of double words e.g. שלח תשלח). But this is about the language itself. Obviously the Torah uses the language rather than inventing a word. Now, using the idea of Lashon Kodesh being the primal language you can delve into that angle, but as for the Torah it's being written in an established language.

Comment: "Ish is used as man and Baal is used as husband": and _ish_ is used as husband, too. (Citation needed.)